How to find source of running water outside property
There’s a constant running water sound near the drain pipes on the outside of my property. I have turned the water off inside but the water flow continues outside. Any ideas what the problem is? Do I need to contact United Utilities?

Drain and supply pipes are usually close together.  Have you noticed any flow reduction inside?  Do you have a water meter and is it still running with the water off?

There’s no reduction in flow inside. Don’t have a water meter. Yes it still runs with the water off.

Contact United.  Might be a storm sewer, might be a leak in the supply pipe, might be an underground water flow/stream, but United should have the people or know who to contact to find the source.  Hearing a water flow underground is rare.

what is United Utilities?

Thank you so much for your response, it’s a great help. I’ll  contact them asap.
